# can i get realtime user login list in firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to create an app that displays the list of users who are logged in realtime, and if the user closes the app it will automatically be deleted from the list of users who are logging .. can i make it in firebase, or what technology is suitable to make it.

Comment: create your custom user database and use flag is online when ever user resume his/her app set that tag to true and when ever user destroy or pause app set that flag to false and store in database.!

Comment: A common way to implement this is through a so-called presence system through the Firebase Realtime Database. See the [sample presence system in the Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-presence).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase does not return list of user logged in your app through api. You can see that list on Firebase Console.

Other than this, you can do this by implementing custom WebService that help you in login and store all credentials in database. So that you can easily get list of all logged in users through any api WebService.

Comment: how can you see them via firebase console? couldnt find that option

Answer (score 1):

You have to create your custom web API to handle with active users.
Although Firebase show active users in Firebase Console, it does not return what u want.